# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException, how to correct it?

Tags: java, apache, exception, tomcat7, illegalstateexception

Why this exception printing all the time when run the server?

`NFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.net.BindException.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createLinkFailureMessageBasedOnHeuristics(SQLError.java:1220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException.<init>(CommunicationsException.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your old mysql-connector-java-5.X-bin.jar to latest mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar

Get it here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/